# Transformation of the density operator with partial decoherence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

I'm trying to understand the transformation of a quantum state with partial decoherence.

An article says that if $\rho = \left| \Psi \right>\left< \Psi \right| $ is the density operator of the state $\left| \Psi \right>$, a partial decoherence transforms $\rho$ into $\rho^D =(1-p)\rho + p\cdot\text{diag}(\rho)$, where $0\leq p \leq 1$ could be understood as the probability of measure the state (so $p=0$ means no decoherence and $p=1$ means total decoherence).

My first question is how the state (and not the density operator) is transformed. I suppose that I can do the inner product so $\left| \Psi \right>$ transforms into $\left| \Psi \right>^D= (1-p)\left| \Psi \right>+p\cdot \text{diag}(\left| \Psi \right>\left< \Psi \right|)\left| \Psi \right>$. Is this correct?

My second question is what does total decoherence means. As far as I know, total decoherence appears when you measure a quantum state and then it becomes a classical state. But for $p=1$, the transformation is $\rho^D_{p=1} = \text{diag}(\rho)$. Why is this equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The form written in your article says that, with probability $p$, the state loses all of the off-diagonal elements in some particular basis; i.e., the state loses all "coherences" in a particular basis with probability $p$. The remaining probability $1-p$ leaves the state unchanged.

You cannot answer the question in terms of pure states, because this process inherently makes a state more mixed! That is why there is no final pure state $|\Psi\rangle^D$ with which you can express your final result. Both pure and mixed states are states; I urge you to avoid referring only to pure states like $|\psi\rangle$ as a state, because density operators $\rho$ are states, too. So the first answer is no, this is not correct.

Total decoherence in this case means that the state transforms into a mixed state with no off-diagonal elements ("coherences"). This means that it behaves exactly the same as a classical (non-interfering, probabilistic) mixture of the basis states, with no possible interference effects arising if you measure the state in some superposition basis.

---

If this is confusing to you, you should read more about the difference between a superposition and a mixture. An initial pure state might be $$|\psi\rangle=\sqrt{q}|\uparrow\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sqrt{1-q}|\downarrow\rangle.$$ After undergoing complete decoherence in this $\uparrow/\downarrow$ basis, the state becomes mixed:
$$\rho^D_{p=1}=q|\uparrow\rangle\langle\uparrow|+(1-q)|\downarrow\rangle\langle\downarrow|.$$ All of the phase information $\phi$ is lost in the decohered state. If you measure either state in the $\uparrow/\downarrow$ basis, you will get the same probability distribution: $q$ and $1-q$. But if you measure in some other basis, the statistics will be different. For example, if you measure in the $$|\pm\rangle=\frac{|\uparrow\rangle\pm|\downarrow\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$ basis, the pure superposition state will have probabilities
$$P_\pm(|\psi\rangle)=\left|\sqrt{q}\pm\sqrt{1-q}e^{i\phi}\right|^2/2=(1\pm 2\sqrt{q}\sqrt{1-q}\cos\phi)/2$$ while the mixed (classical-like) state will show no interference
$$P_\pm(\rho^D_{p=1})=\frac{q}{2}+\frac{1-q}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Another way of looking at this is expressing everything as a matrix in the $\uparrow/\downarrow$ basis and seeing that the decoherence simply decreases the magnitudes of the off-diagonal elements:
$$|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\begin{pmatrix}q&\sqrt{q}\sqrt{1-q}e^{i\phi}\\\sqrt{q}\sqrt{1-q}e^{-i\phi} &1-q\end{pmatrix}$$ transforms into
$$\rho^D=\begin{pmatrix}q&(1-p)\sqrt{q}\sqrt{1-q}e^{i\phi}\\(1-p)\sqrt{q}\sqrt{1-q}e^{-i\phi} &1-q\end{pmatrix}.$$ The off-diagonal terms shrink with increasing $p$. Again, "decoherence" is always with respect to a particular basis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I don't understand how to calculate the probability of a state for the mixed state $\rho$.  For example, the probability of $\left|\uparrow\right>$ in your first equation state $\left|\Psi\right>$ is $\left|\left<\uparrow | \Psi \right>\right|^2 = q$, but what about the probability of $\left|\uparrow\right>$ in the (mixed) state $\rho$?

My other question is: If $U$ is an unitary operator and $U\left|\Psi\right> = \left|\Psi_f\right>$, how can I calculate the probability if we add the decoherence (and I need to apply $U$ on $\rho$?

Comment: The measurement probability can be calculated as $P_{\uparrow} = \mathrm{tr}[|\!\uparrow\rangle\langle\uparrow\!|\rho]$, and the expectation value of an observable $O$ is $\langle O \rangle_{\rho} = \mathrm{tr}[O\rho]$. For your second question, if $|\Psi_f\rangle = U|\Psi\rangle$ then clearly $|\Psi_f\rangle\langle\Psi_f| = U|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|U^{\dagger} = U\rho U^{\dagger}$.